# Using SHP files to draw a density map

Tags: plotting, import, geography

[image]My SHP file of census block groups has polygons and associated employment data for each block group.  Is there a simple way to draw an employment density map?  I've played around with GeoRegionValuePlot without success.  There must be a simple way to link the geography to the employment data and then draw a map.  Thanks![image: ![Output showing geometry and employment data]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DfFl.png)

Mathematica Notebook:
http://artosullivan.com/GIS_PDX.nb
Shape file:
http://artosullivan.com/PDX_05_07.shp

Comment: Can you upload an example file somewhere and link to it here?

Comment: http://artosullivan.com/GIS%20Help.pdf

Comment: I was talking about the *.shp file, actually. How can you be helped by others if they don't have a file to work with?

Comment: Ooooops.  Sorry about the mixup.  I'll upload the shp file to the same website (artosullivan.com) and let you know when it's ready to access.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: OK. I uploaded the shp file along with a Mathematica notebook that shows my inability to get GeoRegionValuePlot to do the simplest of tasks.  I reduced the gas data to two polygons, without success.  One curiosity is that the transpose function works with the 2-polygon case, but doesn't seem to work for the larger dataset.   Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please edit your question to link to these files, then.

Comment: http://artosullivan.com/PDX_05_07.shp
 http://artosullivan.com/GIS PDX.nb

Comment: Again, please notice the "edit" link at the bottom of your question. Click on that, and append your links to your question.